# uWSGI segmentation fault when using Django and python requests

Tags: python, django, python-requests, uwsgi

I am running `Django 2.0` app with `uWSGI 2.0.17` and `python 3.4` on an `openSUSE Leap 42.3 x86-64` server and it's working fine

the problem is when trying to send http request using [python requests librarys](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) uWSGI segmentation fault occures

here is the log from uwsgi

```
   2018-04-10 06:46:15,136 | DEBUG | Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.googleapis.com
    !!! uWSGI process 30352 got Segmentation Fault !!!
    *** backtrace of 30352 ***
    /usr/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x2e) [0x46b92e]
    /usr/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x21) [0x46bcc1]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x34940) [0x7fb169878940]
    /home/pw/venv/lib64/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-34m.so(+0xb2aa) [0x7fb1661542aa]
    /home/pw/venv/lib64/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-34m.so(+0xcd0f) [0x7fb166155d0f]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x413c) [0x7fb169f1673c]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x619) [0x7fb169f1c3b9]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3a36) [0x7fb169f16036]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3fe5) [0x7fb169f165e5]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x619) [0x7fb169f1c3b9]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3a36) [0x7fb169f16036]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x619) [0x7fb169f1c3b9]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3a36) [0x7fb169f16036]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x619) [0x7fb169f1c3b9]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3a36) [0x7fb169f16036]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x619) [0x7fb169f1c3b9]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(+0xd7854) [0x7fb169ef7854]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x4a) [0x7fb169ef2eca]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x2364) [0x7fb169f14964]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x2b0) [0x7fb169f1c050]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(+0xd7854) [0x7fb169ef7854]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x4a) [0x7fb169ef2eca]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x2364) [0x7fb169f14964]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x619) [0x7fb169f1c3b9]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(+0xd7854) [0x7fb169ef7854]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x4a) [0x7fb169ef2eca]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x2364) [0x7fb169f14964]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x2b0) [0x7fb169f1c050]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(+0xd7854) [0x7fb169ef7854]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x4a) [0x7fb169ef2eca]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x2364) [0x7fb169f14964]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x619) [0x7fb169f1c3b9]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3a36) [0x7fb169f16036]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3fe5) [0x7fb169f165e5]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3fe5) [0x7fb169f165e5]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3fe5) [0x7fb169f165e5]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x2b0) [0x7fb169f1c050]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(+0xd7854) [0x7fb169ef7854]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x4a) [0x7fb169ef2eca]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x2364) [0x7fb169f14964]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x619) [0x7fb169f1c3b9]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3a36) [0x7fb169f16036]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x619) [0x7fb169f1c3b9]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3a36) [0x7fb169f16036]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x619) [0x7fb169f1c3b9]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(+0xd7854) [0x7fb169ef7854]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x4a) [0x7fb169ef2eca]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x2364) [0x7fb169f14964]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x619) [0x7fb169f1c3b9]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(+0xd7854) [0x7fb169ef7854]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x4a) [0x7fb169ef2eca]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x2364) [0x7fb169f14964]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3fe5) [0x7fb169f165e5]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x619) [0x7fb169f1c3b9]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3a36) [0x7fb169f16036]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x2b0) [0x7fb169f1c050]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(+0xd75c8) [0x7fb169ef75c8]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x4a) [0x7fb169ef2eca]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(+0xd431a) [0x7fb169ef431a]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x4a) [0x7fb169ef2eca]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(+0x7d09a) [0x7fb169e9d09a]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x4a) [0x7fb169ef2eca]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x3ea8) [0x7fb169f164a8]
    /usr/lib64/libpython3.4m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x619) [0x7fb169f1c3b9]
    *** end of backtrace ***
    DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 30352) died :( trying respawn ...
    Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 30481)
```

**here is myapp.uwsgi.ini**

```
   [uwsgi]

    # Django-related settings
    # the base directory (full path)
    chdir = /home/pw

    # Django's wsgi file
    wsgi-file = /home/pw/public/wsgi.py

    # the virtualenv (full path)
    home = /home/pw/venv

    # process-related settings
    # master
    master = true

    # maximum number of worker processes
    processes = 4
    threads = 5

    # the socket (use the full path to be safe
    socket = /home/pw/pw.sock

    # ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
    chmod-socket = 664

    # clear environment on exit
    vacuum = true
```

**and here is the python code that is raising the exception**

```
   def get_account_info(self, id_token):
            request_ref = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo?key={0}".format(self.api_key)
            headers = {"content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
            data = json.dumps({"idToken": id_token})
            request_object = requests.post(request_ref, headers=headers, data=data)
            raise_detailed_error(request_object)
            return request_object.json()
```

> any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Is this the only request failing or the entire django app in down?

Comment: The requests are failing, and the django app is working fine

Comment: Can you try to add `enable-threads = true` in the uWSGI config

Comment: I try adding `enable-threads = true` in the uWSGI config but it doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [uwsgi segmentation fault when serving a django application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498240/uwsgi-segmentation-fault-when-serving-a-django-application)