# uwsgi segmentation fault when serving a django application

Tags: django, psycopg2, uwsgi

I am trying to migrate a django application from one server to another. The application is working fine on the old server.

On the new server, the application works fine when used using Django's runserver.

To test the django application under uwsgi, I used

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi
```

This opens the django admin page as expected but as soon as I try to login, uwsgi gets a segmentation fault error which is as follows.

Would greatly appreciate if anybody could help understand what this means, and how might I fix this.

---

```
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 15398, cores: 1)
!!! uWSGI process 15398 got Segmentation Fault !!!
*** backtrace of 15398 ***
uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x35) [0x5569e2f17555]
uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x23) [0x5569e2f17903]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x35fc0) [0x7f0dd221bfc0]
/home/vikas/ssersurvey/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-1d6df745.so.1.0.2p(ssl3_cleanup_key_block+0xb) [0x7f0dd0241cab]
/home/vikas/ssersurvey/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-1d6df745.so.1.0.2p(ssl3_clear+0x16) [0x7f0dd023f5a6]
/home/vikas/ssersurvey/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-1d6df745.so.1.0.2p(tls1_clear+0x9) [0x7f0dd024b219]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1(SSL_new+0x43f) [0x7f0dd2bf376f]
/home/vikas/ssersurvey/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-3a62a61f.so.5.11(+0x23969) [0x7f0dd04d6969]
/home/vikas/ssersurvey/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-3a62a61f.so.5.11(+0x24fc5) [0x7f0dd04d7fc5]
/home/vikas/ssersurvey/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-3a62a61f.so.5.11(PQconnectPoll+0xb78) [0x7f0dd04c1ba8]
/home/vikas/ssersurvey/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-3a62a61f.so.5.11(+0xfa28) [0x7f0dd04c2a28]
/home/vikas/ssersurvey/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-3a62a61f.so.5.11(PQconnectdb+0x1f) [0x7f0dd04c541f]
/home/vikas/ssersurvey/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x12651) [0x7f0dd0716651]
/home/vikas/ssersurvey/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x133df) [0x7f0dd07173df]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x1fcab2) [0x7f0dd25d9ab2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x89) [0x7f0dd2645e99]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_CallFunction_SizeT+0x124) [0x7f0dd26468b4]
/home/vikas/ssersurvey/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0xc1a8) [0x7f0dd07101a8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyCFunction_Call+0x96) [0x7f0dd25f0fe6]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7940) [0x7f0dd2561f10]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17ba3f) [0x7f0dd2558a3f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x3e) [0x7f0dd25594fe]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x23cc63) [0x7f0dd2619c63]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x48) [0x7f0dd26466d8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x3de5) [0x7f0dd255e3b5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17a8a3) [0x7f0dd25578a3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c2eb) [0x7f0dd25592eb]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec2) [0x7f0dd255f492]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17a8a3) [0x7f0dd25578a3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c2eb) [0x7f0dd25592eb]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec2) [0x7f0dd255f492]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17a8a3) [0x7f0dd25578a3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c2eb) [0x7f0dd25592eb]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec2) [0x7f0dd255f492]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17ba3f) [0x7f0dd2558a3f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c11e) [0x7f0dd255911e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec2) [0x7f0dd255f492]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17a8a3) [0x7f0dd25578a3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c2eb) [0x7f0dd25592eb]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec2) [0x7f0dd255f492]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17ba3f) [0x7f0dd2558a3f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c11e) [0x7f0dd255911e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x3c95) [0x7f0dd255e265]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x2428a8) [0x7f0dd261f8a8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x239aa6) [0x7f0dd2616aa6]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x239f6a) [0x7f0dd2616f6a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x1fcab2) [0x7f0dd25d9ab2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x89) [0x7f0dd2645e99]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17bee8) [0x7f0dd2558ee8]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec2) [0x7f0dd255f492]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17a8a3) [0x7f0dd25578a3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c2eb) [0x7f0dd25592eb]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec2) [0x7f0dd255f492]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17a8a3) [0x7f0dd25578a3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyFunction_FastCallDict+0x2c3) [0x7f0dd2558e43]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x131) [0x7f0dd2645f41]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_Call_Prepend+0xcd) [0x7f0dd264666d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x89) [0x7f0dd2645e99]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x6bb61) [0x7f0dd2448b61]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x1f5f65) [0x7f0dd25d2f65]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x186ff9) [0x7f0dd2563ff9]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyCFunction_FastCallDict+0x13a) [0x7f0dd25f0d6a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c20c) [0x7f0dd255920c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec2) [0x7f0dd255f492]
*** end of backtrace ***
```

Comment: Seeing a similar issue.
ubuntu 19.04 container, uwsgi 2.0.17.1.

Comment: Strangely my old server has uwsgi 2.0.17.1 too, and does not have any problem. The new one, with the same version of uwsgi, crashes as above. I am at a loss to figure out where the problem might lie.

Answer (score 41):

This error occurs when uwsgi and psycopg are compiled against two different openssl versions.
You have two solution.

- disable ssl of django database configuration (the other answer's solution)
- Install psyocpg2 from source instead of wheel

to install psyocpg2 from source you have to uninstall previous one and try this

```
pip uninstall psycopg2
pip install --no-binary :all: psycopg2
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Same problem on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, uwsgi 2.0.15-debian, upgrading psycopg2-binary to 2.8.2 was enough to solve the problem.

Comment: It also solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124267/problem-with-running-django-with-nginx-and-uwsgi-in-ubuntu. Thank you!

Comment: For me it solved uwsgi+nginx error: Nginx: upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Pyuwsgi](https://pypi.org/project/pyuwsgi/) can be used instead of building uWSGI from source. It is a wheel, but excludes the SSL plugin so it should workaround the incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the connection to PostgreSQL with uWSGI.

Try to disable SSL if feasible in your

```
# Database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sslmode': 'disable'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously this should be only a temporary fix. Do not use it if your db is not on the same machine as your Django app.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It turns out to be caused by the Python package `grpcio (1.34.0)`. Downgrading to `grpcio==1.30.0` solved the problem. This solution is provided by https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/23796

Using `pipenv` (should be the same with `pip`), my exact commands to fix it were:

```
$ pipenv uninstall grpcio
$ pipenv   install grpcio==1.30.0
```