# uWSGI process 17078 got Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, uwsgi, wsgi

I am trying to run a flask app as a service using uwsgi. But getting an error:

> uWSGI process 17078 got Segmentation Fault

Here is what i tried:

**manage.py**

```
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from whatsapp_api import ms_crm_whatsapp, db

migrate = Migrate(ms_crm_whatsapp,db)
manager = Manager(ms_crm_whatsapp)
manager.add_command('db',MigrateCommand)
```

if **name** == '**main**':
       manager.run()

**database.py**

```
from whatsapp_api import db
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON

# print('db##############',db)
class TempTable(db.Model):
    # print('TempTable')
    __tablename__ = 'crm_user_chat_data'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    case_type = db.Column(db.String())
    sub_type = db.Column(db.String())
    number = db.Column(db.String())
    description = db.Column(db.String())
    crm_customer_id = db.Column(db.String())
    title = db.Column(db.String())

    def __init__(self,name,case_type,number,description,sub_type,crm_customer_id,title):
        print('inside __init__')
        self.name = name
        self.case_type = case_type
        self.number = number
        self.description = description
        self.sub_type = sub_type
        self.crm_customer_id = crm_customer_id
        self.title = title

    def __repr__(self):
        print('__repr__',__repr__)
        return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)
```

**whatsapp_api.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import time
import requests
import json
import re
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import psycopg2
ms_crm_whatsapp = Flask(__name__)
ms_crm_whatsapp.config["DEBUG"] = True
ms_crm_whatsapp.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
ms_crm_whatsapp.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'postgresql://user:user_password@localhost:5432/db_name'
db = SQLAlchemy(ms_crm_whatsapp)
from database import TempTable
con = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=db_name user=user password=user_password")
cur = con.cursor()

@ms_crm_whatsapp.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
   return "<h1> Hello welcome to the world of Flask"
```

ms_crm_whatsapp.run(host='0.0.0.0' port=3000)

I was running the app like `python3 manage.py`

**wsgi.py**

```
from whatsapp_api import ms_crm_whatsapp
if __name__ == "__main__":
ms_crm_whatsapp.run()
```

and in the terminal, I tried,

```
 uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:3000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:ms_crm_whatsapp
```

in terminal i getting:

> *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Tue Nov  5 17:05:48 2019]** 
>   compiled with version: 7.4.0 on 05 November 2019 10:27:46
>   os: Linux-4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:24:09 UTC 2019
>   nodename: lenovo-v330-kbir
>   machine: x86_64
>   clock source: unix
>   pcre jit disabled
>   detected number of CPU cores: 8
>   current working directory: /home/user/python-environments/ms_crm_whatsapp_poc
>   detected binary path: /home/user/python-environments/flask_venv/bin/uwsgi
>    **WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager** 
>   your processes number limit is 30456
>   your memory page size is 4096 bytes
>   detected max file descriptor number: 1024
>   lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
>   thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
>   uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 0.0.0.0:3000 fd 3
>   Python version: 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55)  [GCC 8.3.0]
>    **Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads** 
>   Python main interpreter initialized at 0x55f79717ce50
>   your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
>   your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
>   mapped 72920 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
>    **Operational MODE: single process** 
>   unable to load configuration from from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker import main;main(4)
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi.
>     """)
>   !!! uWSGI process 19684 got Segmentation Fault !!!
>    **backtrace of 19684** 
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x2a) [0x55f79555a3da]
>   uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x23) [0x55f79555a7c3]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20) [0x7f8abd3ddf20]
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-c0c2ede4.so.1.0.2q(ssl3_cleanup_key_block+0xb) [0x7f8a81ae1cab]
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-c0c2ede4.so.1.0.2q(ssl3_clear+0x16) [0x7f8a81adf5a6]
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-c0c2ede4.so.1.0.2q(tls1_clear+0x9) [0x7f8a81aeb219]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1(SSL_new+0x3f2) [0x7f8abe9369e2]
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(+0x23969) [0x7f8a81d76969]
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(+0x24fc5) [0x7f8a81d77fc5]
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(PQconnectPoll+0xb78) [0x7f8a81d61ba8]
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(+0xfa28) [0x7f8a81d62a28]
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(PQconnectdb+0x1f) [0x7f8a81d6541f]
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x12b01) [0x7f8a81fb6b01]
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x1388f) [0x7f8a81fb788f]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x1fc402) [0x7f8abdbc4402]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x89) [0x7f8abdc2f169]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_CallFunction_SizeT+0x124) [0x7f8abdc2fb84]
>   /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0xc258) [0x7f8a81fb0258]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyCFunction_Call+0x96) [0x7f8abdbdb976]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x76e0) [0x7f8abdb4cd80]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17bc6f) [0x7f8abdb43c6f]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c35c) [0x7f8abdb4435c]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec3) [0x7f8abdb4a563]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17bc6f) [0x7f8abdb43c6f]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x3e) [0x7f8abdb4472e]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x1b) [0x7f8abdb454ab]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x1887bd) [0x7f8abdb507bd]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyCFunction_Call+0xc1) [0x7f8abdbdb9a1]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x76e0) [0x7f8abdb4cd80]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17bc6f) [0x7f8abdb43c6f]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c35c) [0x7f8abdb4435c]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec3) [0x7f8abdb4a563]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17aa63) [0x7f8abdb42a63]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c51e) [0x7f8abdb4451e]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec3) [0x7f8abdb4a563]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17aa63) [0x7f8abdb42a63]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c51e) [0x7f8abdb4451e]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec3) [0x7f8abdb4a563]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17aa63) [0x7f8abdb42a63]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c51e) [0x7f8abdb4451e]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec3) [0x7f8abdb4a563]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17aa63) [0x7f8abdb42a63]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyFunction_FastCallDict+0x2d5) [0x7f8abdb44085]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x131) [0x7f8abdc2f211]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs+0xe6) [0x7f8abdc2f576]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject+0x45c) [0x7f8abda38b2c]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x77ca) [0x7f8abdb4ce6a]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17bc6f) [0x7f8abdb43c6f]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x3e) [0x7f8abdb4472e]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x1b) [0x7f8abdb454ab]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x1887bd) [0x7f8abdb507bd]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyCFunction_Call+0xc1) [0x7f8abdbdb9a1]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x76e0) [0x7f8abdb4cd80]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17bc6f) [0x7f8abdb43c6f]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c35c) [0x7f8abdb4435c]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec3) [0x7f8abdb4a563]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17aa63) [0x7f8abdb42a63]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c51e) [0x7f8abdb4451e]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec3) [0x7f8abdb4a563]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17aa63) [0x7f8abdb42a63]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c51e) [0x7f8abdb4451e]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4ec3) [0x7f8abdb4a563]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17aa63) [0x7f8abdb42a63]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x17c51e) [0x7f8abdb4451e]
>    **end of backtrace ***

Comment: might be related -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498240/uwsgi-segmentation-fault-when-serving-a-django-application