# Python 3.2 - uWSGI process got Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, nginx, build, compilation, uwsgi

**INTRODUCTION:**

It is a web application environment using Python 3.2, NGINX and uWSGI.

Python 3.2, NGINX and uWSGI components was installed via build and installation ("./configure", "make" and "make install") and they use OpenSSL 1.0.X also installed via build and installation.

The application is running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

**PROBLEM:**

The application cannot start and the uWSGI log shows the information below...

```
Thu Jan 21 21:44:37 2021 - Respawned uWSGI worker 4 (new pid: 99572)
Thu Jan 21 21:44:37 2021 - worker 3 buried after 0 seconds
Thu Jan 21 21:44:37 2021 - worker 7 buried after 0 seconds
Thu Jan 21 21:44:37 2021 - worker 1 buried after 0 seconds
Thu Jan 21 21:44:37 2021 - worker 8 buried after 0 seconds
Thu Jan 21 21:44:37 2021 - worker 5 buried after 0 seconds
Thu Jan 21 21:44:37 2021 - received message 0 from emperor
Thu Jan 21 21:44:37 2021 - SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
Thu Jan 21 21:44:37 2021 - mem-collector thread started for worker 4
Thu Jan 21 21:44:37 2021 - !!! uWSGI process 99543 got Segmentation Fault !!!
Thu Jan 21 21:44:37 2021 - *** backtrace of 99543 ***
/usr/local/lb/uwsgi_ve32/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x2e) [0x556d323f077e]
/usr/local/lb/uwsgi_ve32/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x27) [0x556d323f0b67]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x46210) [0x7f60a0f33210]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x186b7e) [0x7f60a1073b7e]
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0(+0x12254c) [0x7f60a147054c]
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0(lh_insert+0x56) [0x7f60a14707e6]
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0(OBJ_NAME_add+0x74) [0x7f60a13bbc84]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1(+0x36392) [0x7f60a0067392]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x1247f) [0x7f60a181547f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1(CRYPTO_THREAD_run_once+0xd) [0x7f609ff3d78d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_init_ssl+0x5b) [0x7f60a006757b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5(+0x26304) [0x7f60a00ea304]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5(PQconnectPoll+0xe80) [0x7f60a00d4ec0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5(+0x11fd7) [0x7f60a00d5fd7]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq.so.5(PQconnectdb+0x38) [0x7f60a00d9048]
/usr/local/lb/lbg_ve32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-32m.so(+0x10939) [0x7f60a012e939]
/usr/local/lb/lbg_ve32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-32m.so(+0x117a2) [0x7f60a012f7a2]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(+0xab58c) [0x7f60a11c558c]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x5b) [0x7f60a1174dcb]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(_PyObject_CallFunction_SizeT+0xd2) [0x7f60a1175192]
/usr/local/lb/lbg_ve32/lib/python3.2/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-32m.so(+0xbace) [0x7f60a0129ace]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x76e3) [0x7f60a1210b53]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x733) [0x7f60a12115e3]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(+0x81f92) [0x7f60a119bf92]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x5b) [0x7f60a1174dcb]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xfb9) [0x7f60a120a429]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x733) [0x7f60a12115e3]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(+0x81f92) [0x7f60a119bf92]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x5b) [0x7f60a1174dcb]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xfb9) [0x7f60a120a429]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x733) [0x7f60a12115e3]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x65f1) [0x7f60a120fa61]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x670c) [0x7f60a120fb7c]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x733) [0x7f60a12115e3]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(+0x81eaf) [0x7f60a119beaf]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x5b) [0x7f60a1174dcb]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(+0x7033c) [0x7f60a118a33c]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x5b) [0x7f60a1174dcb]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(+0xacf47) [0x7f60a11c6f47]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(+0xab58c) [0x7f60a11c558c]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x5b) [0x7f60a1174dcb]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x4106) [0x7f60a120d576]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x670c) [0x7f60a120fb7c]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x670c) [0x7f60a120fb7c]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x733) [0x7f60a12115e3]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x65f1) [0x7f60a120fa61]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x733) [0x7f60a12115e3]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x65f1) [0x7f60a120fa61]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x670c) [0x7f60a120fb7c]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x733) [0x7f60a12115e3]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x65f1) [0x7f60a120fa61]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x670c) [0x7f60a120fb7c]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x733) [0x7f60a12115e3]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x65f1) [0x7f60a120fa61]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x733) [0x7f60a12115e3]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(+0x81f92) [0x7f60a119bf92]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x5b) [0x7f60a1174dcb]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xfb9) [0x7f60a120a429]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x733) [0x7f60a12115e3]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x65f1) [0x7f60a120fa61]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x670c) [0x7f60a120fb7c]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x733) [0x7f60a12115e3]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(+0x81eaf) [0x7f60a119beaf]
/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/libpython3.2m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x5b) [0x7f60a1174dcb]
*** end of backtrace ***
```

**IMPORTANT:**

Appears that the application is "mixing" OpenSSL 1.0.X components with OpenSSL 1.1.X components...

```
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0(+0x12254c) [0x7f60a147054c]
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0(lh_insert+0x56) [0x7f60a14707e6]
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0(OBJ_NAME_add+0x74) [0x7f60a13bbc84]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1(+0x36392) [0x7f60a0067392]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1(CRYPTO_THREAD_run_once+0xd) [0x7f609ff3d78d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_init_ssl+0x5b) [0x7f60a006757b]
```

---

**I really need help with this question... I have tried everything!**

**Thanks! =D**

Comment: Is there a reason you must use OpenSSL 1.0? If not you can install uWSGI using `sudo -H pip3 install uwsgi` or `sudo apt install uwsgi`.

Comment: It is a legacy application and all of its components use OpenSSL 1.0.X. It seems to me that some configuration is missing during the compilation process so that uWSGI consumes "/usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0" (OpenSSL 1.0.X) and not "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 "(OpenSSL 1.1.X). Thanks! =D

Comment: @Selcuk See this thread that addresses a very similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54253374/3223785 . =D

Comment: That makes sense. This might be a weird suggestion but is there any chance that you can run the system on a distro with OpenSSL 1.0.x (such as Ubuntu 16.04) instead?

Comment: @Selcuk Unfortunately not, as the client asked to update to the latest version of Ubuntu (20.04 LTS). Thanks! =D

Comment: Well, you may try running a prebuilt uWSGI then. Possibly one that was compiled on an Ubuntu 16 machine. Sorry, segfaults are hard to debug.

Comment: @Selcuk Yes! That is precisely why I am so "lost"... =|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**CAUSE:** Most modern versions of Ubuntu Server have PostgreSQL 9.4 configured to use *ssl* - *tls* actually - in a version above version 1.0 which is incompatible with Python 3.2 that uses OpenSSL to have the *ssl* resource. When Python 3.2 tries to connect to PostgreSQL 9.4 using *ssl*, some library in use by the first (**psycopg2?**) tries to load a more modern version of OpenSSL compatible with the client, then the application starts to operate with two different versions of OpenSSL - one of which is incompatible with Python 3.2 - which causes a **segmentation fault** error in the application load.

**SOLUTION:**  We can use PostgreSQL 9.4 with a 1.0 version of *ssl* or disable this feature. We chose disable "ssl". The procedure below configures PostgreSQL 9.4 to **do not use** *ssl* to establish connections as was done in the older versions of distros that use PostgreSQL 9.4.

**PROCEDURE:**

Open the file `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/postgresql.conf` - the path may vary - and **comment out** these lines:

`ssl = on                                # (change requires restart)`

... , ...

`ssl_cert_file = '/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem'          # (change requires restart)`

... and...

`ssl_key_file = '/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key'         # (change requires restart)`

Restart the Python 3.2 application and PostgreSQL 9.4.

For PostgreSQL 9.4 the following commands can be used to restart it...

```
systemctl stop postgresql
sleep 2
systemctl start postgresql
```

**Done!
Thanks! =D**